# matplotlib - converting from rgba back to an integer

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a 12 bit camera that takes images in the form of an array (values are integers).  When I save the array through matplotlib as a .png, then read it back, the values are in RGBA (as expected).  From reading the .png, I need to be able to convert it back into it's original integer value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import norm

# simulate some data
x = np.arange(0,100.1,1)
y1 = norm.pdf(x, loc=50, scale=20)
y2 = norm.pdf(x, loc=40, scale=10)
scaler = 1024/np.max(np.outer(y1,y2)) # img is 12 bits
img = np.outer(y1,y2)*scaler
img = img.astype(np.uint16) # force to be 16 bit as there is no 12 bit in np
print(np.max(img), np.min(img), img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

plt.imsave(r"../img/sim.png", img, vmin=0, vmax=2**12, cmap='viridis')
img2 = plt.imread(r"../img/sim.png")
img2 # can we convert these RGBA values back to the original integers?
```

I can't figure out how to convert these (efficiently) back into the original integers.  I believe this is possible as I've read that .png uses lossless compression.  Basically I need to establish that img2 is equal to img.

I feel like I'm definitely missing something basic here...

Comment: Please be a little more concise, as well as comprehensive, by providing a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Perhaps you could show us what the current and the desired formats look like?
Your title was also confusing: would you like to convert to RGBA floats, or to a single color integer?

Comment: I'm confused about the comprehensive part as I say that I need to establish that img2 is equal to img.  I understand that the title should say integer (although float would suffice since we can map the 0 to 1 float to an integer by reversing the normalization that matplotlib does).

Comment: I don't know what your workflow looks like, but I think it would be way easier to use numpy and save `img`. You can then load it and it will have the right type and numbers

Comment: yea there's a different application that basically requires the .png file.  trying to reduce data sprawl by saving it multiple times.  thought it'd be easy to inverse the colormap...

Comment: @CJStevens not everyone is familiar with the data formats you use, so a comment or excerpt of the data format could have been helpful (and more comprehensive ;-) ). Example: `my_rgba = initialize_rgba_value()  # format (uints with max 255): [255, 0, 100, 50]`. I suppose many of us know what RGBA values are, but I've never heard of a single-integer representation of color values before (although an obvious implementation comes to mind because 4*8bits = 32 bits ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following line:

```
plt.imsave(r"../img/sim.png", img, vmin=0, vmax=2**12, cmap='viridis')
```

When you specify a colormap with `cmap='viridis'` it quantises your image down to 8-bits so it can use a 256-colour palette (the biggest possible) in the PNG image and boom! your 16-bit data are toast (lost).

If you use `imageio` it can save 16-bit data, so you would replace the above line with:

```
import imageio                                                                                                                         
...
imageio.imwrite('12-bit.png',img)
```

That will preserve your 16-bit data. A potential issue is that the data are now greyscale and difficult to see. That may not be a problem as you may have saved the data just to store it rather than to visualise it. I guess you would then have two options:

- either store the file twice (disk is cheap) - once in greyscale for storage and once with viridis colormap for visualisation, or,
- just store once in greyscale and make a *"viewer"* tool that loads the greyscale and renders it with the viridis palette.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was realizing about the 8 bit color map last night but didn't get around to putting it all together.  I tested your result here and thought i'd show for completeness.  
`img2 = plt.imread(r"../img/12-bit.png")`
`((img2*2**16).astype('uint16') == img).any()`
I'll probably go with option #1 outlined above.